# Laravel - translate auth and form validation

Tags: php, laravel

I have generated the default Laravel auth module, but I want to be able to use it in different languages. 
Under lang I can see `auth.php` and `passwords.php` which have a few error messages, I was able to create my own lang folder and translate these. But this seems incomplete. I also want to translate everything in my views, but it seems hardcoded. For example in `login.blade.php` the label for email looks like this:

```
<label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
```

My question is that why is the auth module only partly in translation files and the rest is hardcoded? Am i misunderstanding something or is the solution really to add "email" to translation file and change the view like this:

@lang('auth.email')

Also a second question is about the validation popups in views. For example if I don't fill any lines and press login a popup appears saying `"Please fill out this field"`. Where is this coming from and how do I translate it?

Comment: Answer to your second question. This message pops up because the input field has the required attribute set and the message is shown by the browser.

Comment: Please specify your laravel version.

Comment: I have similar question to this one, please, see if you can help me. [it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851907/laravel-default-auth-modult-translation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translations in the Auth package pertain to standard messages returned to the user when attempting to login, reset passwords, etc.

If you want to translate field names, error messages, etc, then you can do so by creating your own language files under `resources/lang/{lang_code}`, or by downloading those shared within the community. For example, [this repo](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang).

As for using translations in your templates, you can use the `trans` helper. See the following example, where `lang.login.email` would be mapped to a value in your language file:

```
<label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ trans('lang.login.email') }}</label>


// resources/lang/en/lang.php
return [
    'login' => [
        'email' => 'Email address',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I have similar question to this one, please, see if you can help me. [it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851907/laravel-default-auth-modult-translation)