# Laravel default auth module translation

Tags: laravel-5, localization, translation

I have generated the default Laravel auth module.

Everywhere in the blades of the module, I see Double Underscore `__` function assuming that translation is almost there.

for example

```
<li>
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">
    {{ __('Login') }}
  </a>
</li>
```

My question: Where is the translation file? Where should I put it, if I create one?

I mean, if I go to the Laravel documentation site there are examples like this

```
echo __('messages.welcome');
```

with explanations

> For example, let's retrieve the `welcome` translation string from the `resources/lang/messages.php` language file:

BUT in my example above there is no file name specified. It is only text:

```
__('Login')
```

Question is: What is used for the language file if no file specified? Is there any default? Where does it sit? Where was it set?

Comment: A quick Google search yields two entries in the Laravel docs - [1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#strings) and [2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#retrieving-translation-strings). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Can you tell, after using this links, where is a translation file for a construction like `__('Login')`? I cannot.

Comment: The second link covers all of that.

Comment: Sorry, It is not clear for me. It has similar example `echo __('I love programming.');` but It does not say where the translation should come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys)
Have an instruction about the json file. Yes it is not php, but json file. Example would be:

```
resources/lang/es.json
```

content

```
{
    "I love programming.": "Me encanta programar."
}
```

Usage

```
echo __('I love programming.');
```

Answer (score 14):

All the language translation files in Laravel should be stored in `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/resources/lang`. When you make an Auth with artisan, it automatically creates it. But if you can't find it, then create manually.

(1)

There's a way to using translation strings as keys by the docs. In this method you can create a JSON file in `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/resources/lang` with the name of your local, for example for Spanish name it `es.json` or German `de.json`, it depends on your local name.

Now create a JSON object and put the translations with the string name you used in your blade:

```
{
   "Login": "Welcome to Login Page!",
   "Logout": "You are logged out!",
}
```

Then use the PHP double underscores method to call your translations in blades:

```
{{ __('Login') }}
```

(2)

Create a file named `auth.php` in `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/resources/lang` directory. then put a simple php array like this on it:

```
<?php
  
  return [

    /*
      Translations go here...
    */

  ];`
```

Then add your translate strings to it:

```
  <?php
  
  return [

    'Login' => 'Welcome to Login Page!',
    'Logout' => 'You are logged out!',

  ];`
```

Now in the blade template simply do this:

```
<li>
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">
   {{ __('auth.Login') }}
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is a valid point of view. Have you fond it in documentation somewhere?

Comment: Yes, according to the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#defining-translation-strings) if you want to store all translations in one json file you can use translation strings without pointing to the file. You write `__('Login')` in your template file, then in the languages directory create one json file like `en.json`. Now you can write all translate strings like this `{
     "Login": "This is the login page",
     "Logout": "You've logged out"
}`. You can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452410/4428809).

Comment: thanks for the comment but it is very different from the answer that you are commenting. What version of laravel is it?

Comment: Sorry if there was some misunderstanding, This feature comes from version 5.4 and still works (to 5.6).

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev I describe the answer for you in full detail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was looking this for an hour online!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are no translation file for the default `__('Login')`, `__('Register')`, ... provided by laravel.

By default if no translation is found for `__('foobar')`, laravel just uses the string in the parentheses. So here, assuming there is no translation file, `__('Login')` is expanded to `'Login'`.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. Jila explained that there is no file where Login translation is located.
I'll just add for the full answer that by default laravel checks the folder lang/en/* because config('app.locale') is set to 'en'. If you change locale to 'ru', laravel will look into lang/ru/*

Comment: You just made a good point. I was confused searching for this translation but couldn't find the associated file. I now understand it.